# Hover a DIV on ThreeJS Object keeping it's location sync with 3D world

Tags: javascript, html, 3d, three.js

How to place a DIV in 2D space over a 3D Object in ThreeJs so that when the world rotates, the DIV is also moved along with it.

Note: The 3D Object is loaded from a model, so there are groups inside groups and then a mesh.

[image: Hover a DIV on ThreeJS Object keeping it's location sync with 3D world]

Comment: I have prepared a jsfiddle to explain the usage:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/umairrafiq/b3mvLxk7/7/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AS well as the sprite, you can also do a screen translation if you prefer to use divs for whatever reason.

Where obj is an object3d, and renderer, camera are defined and available, the x and y values from the function can be passed to CSS:

```
function getScreenTranslation (obj) {

    var vector = new THREE.Vector3();
    var widthHalf = 0.5 * renderer.context.canvas.width;
    var heightHalf = 0.5 * renderer.context.canvas.height;

    var bbox = new THREE.BoundingBoxHelper(obj, 0xFFFFFF);

    bbox.update();

            bbox.updateMatrixWorld();
            bbox.updateMatrix();

    vector.setFromMatrixPosition(bbox.matrixWorld);
    vector.project(camera);
    vector.x = vector.x * widthHalf + widthHalf;
    vector.y = -(vector.y * heightHalf) + heightHalf;
    return {
            x: vector.x,
            y: vector.y
    };
```

};

depending on your setup, when the scene changes and objects move you'll need to update the div positions. You can do this with camera or controls. Since my boilerplate only changes the world with controls input I use a change event function.

```
this.controls.addEventListener('change', my_change_event_function);
```

It's difficult to make an example here because it's difficult to know what divs you're managing. But for example i manage a multidimensional array of 3d objects and corresponding labels in jquery divs.

The array has the structure:
[[div, object3d],[div, object3d],[div, object3d],[div, object3d]]

and the change event on the controls runs the following:

```
        if (labels !== undefined) {
                for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
                        var position = getScreenTranslation(labels[i][1]);
                        labels[i][0].css({
                                left: position.x,
                                top: position.y
                        });
                }
        }
```

Edit working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dpe5r41g/

Comment: I have tried to use your method in this fiddle. It just stays at the center:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/umairrafiq/b3mvLxk7/7/

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I forgot to do some matrix updates to the bbox. I have made a functioning fiddle @ https://jsfiddle.net/vvq35tc8/